# Call function on textchange in span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function in My big commerce project when the `<span> </span>` text has changed i want to call that particular function.For ex., If the  tag contains `<span>Hi</span>`,when the text `Hi` changed to `<span>Hello</span>` means i want to call the function `test()`.

```
function test(){
    alert("Hi you are authorised for this page")
}
```

Comment: What will be the trigger for `<span>` text to change?

Comment: something is missing here.

Comment: When the value changed in the dropdown means the `<span>` text value wants to be changed. @JohnroePauloCañamaque

Comment: @Gowri what is missing here?

Comment: @SabariKarthik Like what Gowri said, there is something missing, and what you have said to me is the missing part.

Comment: @SabariKarthik call a function in dropdown change event and change the span text using it's id or class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

HTML:

```
<span id="mytext">Hi</span>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#mytext').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(e){
    if($(this).text() == 'Hello')
      alert("Hi you are authorised for this page");
});
```

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b3fztbh0/)**